# How to call page method without page-reload?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

It might be seems to be FAQ. but I got Something in my mind and let me explain that.
I search an test many way's for doing that and at the end I found these soultion:

1. [Jquery With Ajax](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
2. Webform_Docallback
3. Script Manager and UpdatePanel

so what I need is Something Like first solution, but also want to access to **`this`** object and even **`page controls`**. and Reason don't use the second and third solution is they call `Page-Reload first and then call that method`. So that's what I Need!

Is there any solution? any tip's?

***`Additional Info :`***
I need something like: call Method by `button_click` and go to the server side. in Server-Side call Wcf-Service and finally do something. (like binding grid datasources, change textbox values or etc).

Almost *`jQuery with Ajax`* is what I need. but I have these problem with this way!

1. didn't have access to this Object
2. didn't have access to Page-Controls

> So How to solve these issue's?

Comment: I'd go with jquery on this one. Phil Haack recently released this sweet addon to MVC for calling action methods from JS: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/18/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+haacked+%28you%27ve+been+HAACKED%29

Answer (score 3):

For the first one

Create a WebMethod in the .cs file

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Foo() 
{ 
  //......
}
```

If you want to use session you should

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] or [WebMethod(true)]
public static string Foo() 
{
    //......
}
```

Then , invoke the webmothod by js

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json",
url: "WebForm1.aspx/Foo",
data: "{}",
dataType: "json",
success: function(){.......}
});
```

Hope it useful...

Answer (score 3):

```
        [WebMethod()]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()] 
        public static void YourTaskNAme(Your Parameter)
        {
             // Yuor Code here
        }
```

Update the script manager to have the following property `EnablePageMethods="true"`

finally use the javascript to call this method

```
PageMethods.YourTaskNAme(Your Parameter, OnMethodFinished);

function OnMethodFinished() {
alert('Call to function worked.')
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass any logic you have inside your `Page_Load` method by checking the `ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack` property with a `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: See http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-determine-whether-an-asynchronous-partial-postback-has-occurred-on-page.aspx